# TinyMCE image manager plugin "Archiv"

Tags: tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE image manager plugin **[Archiv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/archiv/)**.

I configured as recommended

in config.base.php, if I set

```
'upload_path'           => '/var/www/example/template/', 
'upload_uri'            => 'http://www.example.com/template/',
```

it works fine, but if I use:

```
'upload_path' => $upload_path,
'upload_uri' => $upload_uri,
```

where

```
$dir = $client->agencycode;  //which is string 
$upload_path = "/var/www/example/template/$dir/";
$upload_uri = "http://www.example.com/template/$dir/";
```

The plugin work properly except uploading files.
I can create directory, list directory, delete files. The only thing do not work is upload a files.

Is there anyway or anything need to configure in order to make uploads work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with a Black background while uploading transparent png files, change the function `create_png(...)` in `Archiv->php->connector` to the following code:

```
function create_png($file, $width, $height, $pic_new_width, $pic_new_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height){
        #fetch the extention from the file
        $file_path  = substr($file,0,strrpos($file,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
        $file_name  = substr($file,strlen($file_path)+1, (strrpos($file,".")-(strlen($file_path)+1)));
        $file_ext   = substr($file,strrpos($file,"."));

        #create the picture
        $pic            = imagecreatetruecolor($pic_new_width, $pic_new_height);
        $source         = imagecreatefrompng($file);


        // enable alpha blending on the destination image.
        imagealphablending($pic, true); 

        // Allocate a transparent color and fill the new image with it.
        // Without this the image will have a black background instead of being transparent.
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha( $pic, 0, 0, 0, 127 );
        imagefill( $pic, 0, 0, $transparent );


        $imgcpyrsmpld   = imagecopyresampled( $pic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $pic_new_width, $pic_new_height, $width, $height );

        imagealphablending($pic, false); 

        // save the alpha
        imagesavealpha($pic,true); 

        header('Content-type: image/png'); 

        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '<')){
            $imagepng   = imagepng($pic, $file_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name.$file_ext);
        }
        else{
            $imagepng   = imagepng($pic, $file_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name.$file_ext, 0);
        }       

        $imagedestroy   = imagedestroy($pic);

        list($width, $height) = @getimagesize($file);

        #create the thumb
        $thumb              = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
        $source2            = imagecreatefrompng( $file );      

        // enable alpha blending on the destination image.
        imagealphablending($thumb, true); 

        // Allocate a transparent color and fill the new image with it.
        // Without this the image will have a black background instead of being transparent.
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha( $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127 );
        imagefill( $thumb, 0, 0, $transparent );

        $imgcpyrsmpld2      = imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

        imagealphablending($thumb, false); 

        // save the alpha
        imagesavealpha($thumb,true); 

        header('Content-type: image/png'); 

        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '<')){
            $imagepng2      = imagepng($thumb, $file_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name.'_thumb'.$file_ext);
        }
        else{
            $imagepng2      = imagepng($thumb, $file_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name.'_thumb'.$file_ext, 0);
        }

        $imagedestroy2      = imagedestroy($thumb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the 'images' plugin instead.
As other mentioned, there is no documentation for this plugin.